# How to get js functions from html using modules and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firebase, require

I have **server.js** file which start the server using Node.js:

```
const EXPRESS = require('express');
const DB = require('./js/db-func');

const APP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const APP = EXPRESS();
const router = EXPRESS.Router();
const PATH = __dirname;

APP.use(EXPRESS.static(__dirname));

router.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${PATH}/index.html`);
});
....
....
```

And i also have **db-func.js** file that hold all my database reltated functions:

```
module.exports = {
// Read from DB
readFromDB(collectionName) {
  const FIREBASE = require('firebase');
  // Initialize Cloud Firestore through Firebase
  if (FIREBASE.apps.length === 0) {
    FIREBASE.initializeApp({
      apiKey: 'someApiKey',
      authDomain: 'myweb.firebaseio.com',
      projectId: 'mywebID',
    });
  }

  // Example: get data from firestore database
  const db = FIREBASE.firestore();
  const object = db.collection(collectionName);
  return object;
},
};
```

I want to use the function **`readFromDB()`** within an **index.html** file when loading it:

```
<body onload = "readFromDB('Orders')">
```

I figured that the function won't be recognized because it's a module.
so i've tried to add to the js scripts definitions in my html page this row:

```
<script type="module" src="js/db-func.js"></script>
```

But, it has no purpose because i want it to required the function from my server.js file, 
as a request to the server. and also, it's not working anyway...

Comment: You can't mix front-end JS with back-end Node JS like this. What you need is an API.

Comment: from the html pages, you have to use the javascript `fetch` api and make rest api calls to your API layers from the UI

Comment: ummm...and how exactly do i do that? dosen't is meant that i need to re-write the scripts?